# What happens to event queue when a node server throws exception

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Lets say, I have a node server. Due to some error the server could not recover and server exits. At this time what will happen to requests or the items in the event queue?

Answer (score 0):

The requests will timeout on the client side, and everything else that was in NodeJS memory will be lost. Since you basically exited the app. You get the same behavior when you exit a game and don't save your progress. The process will be lost :)